# NextJS: Run a Typescript script on the server

Tags: typescript, next.js, ts-node

I have a NextJS/Typescript project where I want to add a CLI script which should process some files on the server.

Unfortunately I don't manage to run the script.

Example script `src/cli.ts`:

```
console.log("Hello world");
// Process files
```

I tried to run the script with:

```
ts-node src/cli.ts
```

But I get this error message:

```
src/cli.ts:1:1 - error TS1208: 'cli.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
```

When I add an empty 'export {}' statement I get this error message:

```
(node:15923) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

As far as I know it is now not possible to use NextJS with ES modules.

Is there another way to run the script in a NextJS project? Maybe I need to change the webpack config?

I'm using the latest versions: Next 11, Typescript 4.3, Node 14.18, ts-node 10.13 with the default `tsconfig.json`, `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @brc-dd answer.

The `--skip-project` flag is now `--skipProject`

And for the new TSConfig to specify when running the script you would need the following:

```
{
  "extends": "ts-node/next/tsconfig.json",

  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      // compilerOptions specified here will override those declared below,
      // but *only* in ts-node.  Useful if you want ts-node and tsc to use
      // different options with a single tsconfig.json.

      "module": "CommonJS",
      "isolatedModules": false
    }
  },

  "compilerOptions": {
    // typescript options here
  }
}
```

All I added to this was: `"module": "CommonJS",`

Answer (score 14):

You can use [TSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx), which plays nicely with NextJS, for both JavaScript and TypeScript. No need for extra configuration or anything.

Install it:

```
yarn add -D tsx
```

Declare your script in `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "my-cli-script": "tsx src/cli.ts"
},
```

Run it:

```
yarn my-cli-script
```

Comment: I was literally going insane. Tried about 20 different solutions, until this worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: @MarekLisý Same here :)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. If you want you can also just `npx tsx path/to/your/script.ts`, without the need to add `tsx` to the dependencies and an appropriate script in package.json.

Comment: I tried a LOT of different things to get my .ts script (used for some db updates) to execute with ts-node and nothing worked.

tsx worked on first try, no changes to tsconfig.json or package.json. Incredible. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Run this instead:

```sh
npx ts-node --skip-project src/cli.ts
```

Reference: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#tsconfig

The `--skip-project` flag will not resolve/load your `tsconfig.json` and, thus, ignore the `"isolatedModules": true` required by Next.js.

You can also create a separate `tsconfig` file for `ts-node` and use the `--project [path]` option.

Another way is to override configuration for `ts-node` in your `tsconfig.json` itself like this:

```
{
  "extends": "ts-node/next/tsconfig.json",

  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      // compilerOptions specified here will override those declared below,
      // but *only* in ts-node.  Useful if you want ts-node and tsc to use
      // different options with a single tsconfig.json.

      "isolatedModules": false
    }
  },

  "compilerOptions": {
    // typescript options here
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#via-tsconfigjson-recommended